# Objective C Using NSScanner to obtain <body> from html

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsscanner

I am trying to create an iOS app simply to extract the  section of a web page.

I have the code working to connect to the URL and store the HTML in an NSString

I have tried this, but I am just getting null strings for my result

```
    NSScanner* newScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlData];
    // Create a new scanner and give it the html data to parse.

    while (![newScanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [newScanner scanUpToString:@"<body>" intoString:NULL];
        // Scam until <body> tag is found

        [newScanner scanUpToString:@"</body>" intoString:&bodyText];
        // Everything up to the end tag will get placed into the memory address of the result string

    }
```

I have tried an alternative way...

```
    NSScanner* newScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlData];
    // Create a new scanner and give it the html data to parse.

    while (![newScanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [newScanner scanUpToString:@"<body" intoString:NULL];
        // Scam until <body> tag is found

        [newScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];
        // Go to end of opening <body> tag

        [newScanner scanUpToString:@"</body>" intoString:&bodyText];
        // Everything up to the end tag will get placed into the memory address of the result string

    }
```

This second way returns a string which starts with `>< script...` etc

If Im honest I don't have a good URL to test this with and I think It may be easier with some help on removing the tags within the body too (like `<p></p>`)

Any help would be very much appriciated

Comment: [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios), [Library](https://github.com/nolanw/HTMLReader)

Comment: Where are you checking `bodyText`? Within the loop  or after?

Comment: By the way, if you're parsing HTML, you might want to use a proper parser, for example [HPPL](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). For an example, see [Ray Wenderlich's How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios).

Comment: I did the checking of bodyText after this while loop. And my specific task is for educational purposes to understand how to these functions are used. Im pretty new to Objective C and iOS so i just wanted to see what i can do this way. I look into other librarys after I have learnt the more basic stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why your first method didn't work. I assume you defined bodyText before that snippet. This code worked fine for me,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *htmlData = @"This is some stuff before <body> this is the body </body> with some more stuff";
    NSScanner* newScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlData];
    NSString *bodyText;
    while (![newScanner isAtEnd]) {
        [newScanner scanUpToString:@"<body>" intoString:NULL];
        [newScanner scanString:@"<body>" intoString:NULL];
        [newScanner scanUpToString:@"</body>" intoString:&bodyText];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",bodyText); // 2015-01-28 15:58:00.360 ScanningOfHTMLProblem[1373:661934] this is the body 
}
```

Notice that I added a call to `scanString:intoString:` to get past the first `"<body>"`.

Comment: Thank you, So i assume that using scanUpToString will stop just before the <body> tag. Is there a good URL to test this problem with?

Comment: @user3012508, yes the scanner will stop just before the "<" in body after that statement. I don't know of any particularly good URL to test this with. After looking at the source code for several web pages, it looks like you might mostly see <body... some other stuff...> rather than <body>. So you might want to scan up to "<body" instead.